# Class does not contain a definition for String ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

It is my default class Login

```
 public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{


public string Insert;


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    public void reset()
    {
        login.Text = "";
        haslo.Text = "";
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Insert = login.Text;
    }
    ...
```

I want to use "Insert" public string in another class but when i'm putting

```
public partial class Account : System.Web.UI.Page 
{

string var = Login.Insert;
}
```

in class "Account" i get an error " **'Login' does not contain a definition for 'Insert'**"

I do not know where is the problem, i am looking for any solution.

Comment: It's public, but not static. Why are you trying to reference a member of another page? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to use login text in  Account class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah that's cause it's a instance variable but you are trying to access it as if it's a `static` member saying `Login.Insert`. Moreover, don't forget that it's a web application and thus best way to access it is using some sort of state management mechanism like `Session` object in your `HttpContext` and thus you can store it in session saying `Session["insert"] = Insert`

In your other page just retrieve it saying `string var = session["insert"]?.ToString()`

SideNote: Use proper naming convention for your class members and variables.

Comment: I was looking for this, thank you.